# PHP while-loop gone wrong

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok so im trying to make a simple trade script i have been trying to find the problem for weeks now i have decided to ask for help. I select some monsters from the db and also the trade info e.g who the trade is from and who its going to. The script goes though ok and say its done but does not do the 2 updates.  It ment to grab the monsters from the db then update there owners. I have session start and the db connect at the top of the page be for anyone says that is the problem

```
} else if ( $_POST['Submit'] == 'Complete' ) {

  //// This is the bit which does the update and does not work

  $TradeID = $_POST['id'];
  $sql12 = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM Trades WHERE ID='$TradeID'" );
  $row12 = mysql_fetch_array( $sql12 ) or die( mysql_error() );

  $unserialize11 = unserialize( $row12['MyPokemon'] );

  foreach ( $unserialize11 as $poke222 ) {
    $sql2 = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM user_pokemon WHERE id='$poke222'" );
    while ( $row2 = mysql_fetch_array( $sql2 ) ) {
      $Update1 = mysql_query( "UPDATE user_pokemon SET  belongsto='".$row12['Me']."' WHERE id='".$row2['ID']."'" );
    }
  }
  $unserialize12 = unserialize( $row12['OtherPokemon'] );
  foreach ( $unserialize12 as $poke122 ) {
    $sql3 = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM user_pokemon WHERE id='$poke122'" );
    while ( $row3 = mysql_fetch_array( $sql3 ) ) {
      $Update1 = mysql_query("UPDATE user_pokemon SET   belongsto='".$row12['OtherPerson']."' WHERE id='".$row3['ID']."'" );
    }
  }

  echo "You have successfully completed trade #".$TradeID."!";
}
} else if ($_GET['action'] == 'delete'){
```

I have just snipped the bit of code which is not working it is grabbing the monsters fine but is just not doing the update i think maybe ive got the }} in the wrong place or maybe have to many ???

Comment: is this some sort of stress-tests for old servers ? Additionally , have you ever tried to **learn SQL** ?! It looks like you cannot even write a simple `JOIN` statement.

Comment: what do you mean stress test ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing_(software)

Comment: scares you ? I now it can be sql injected but this is just to test. e.g the post id bit im gonna make safe after this is on my local host so.

Comment: It's not just the SQL vulnerabilities. It's the indentation, the code quality, the variable naming, the approach to the problem, …

Comment: If you have sufficient reputation, you can clean up formatting for the author ;)

Comment: +1 because this is someone who needs help and at least tried to give enough information to let others help him. That said, the code makes me cry.

Answer (score 0):

Upon cleaning up your formatting, it does appear that you have an extra semicolon, locating at the end of the `if` statement presented here. In your `if` statement, you have 5 instances of `{` and 6 instances of `}`. Removing the last `}` may resolve your issue.

Keeping your code nicely formatting will reduce troubleshooting issues in the future. I've removed much of the body of this code block to reveal the problem-brace:

```
if ( $_POST['Submit'] == 'Complete' ) {
  /* Removed variable assignments */
  /* Removed foreach & while */
  /* Removed variable assignment */
  /* Removed foreach & while */
  /* Removed output */
}
} /* This brace shouldn't be here */
```

Comment: Getting a white page after removing the extra }

Comment: Unfortunately I would not be able to diagnose the cause of the white page without seeing more code. Perhaps you could provide us a larger sample via http://pastebin.com/?

Answer (score 0):

How do you know your script goes throught OK? You aren't checking for success anywhere. Your success message echoes **always** when the submit button is pressed. Maybe you should check for success by checking affected rows.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Maybe your DB structure needs refining too. `While` inside `foreach` twice in the same trade isn't very efficient. Based on your description I would use the following tables:

- `user`: this is for granted...
- `pokemon_gen`: general information about different models.
- `pokemon_unique`: every item should have a unique ID. This table contains FK to owner (user) and to pokemon model. Also info about last trade date, pokemon's condition (if this is a buy and sell database) etc. could be in here (or FK to another more detailed table).
- `trade`: data and info about a **single** trade. Which pokemon was traded from who to whom and when. FK to `pokemon_unique` is needed for that.

You should only need arrays to identify the unique pokemons and their current and future owners. (Doesn't one trade need only two owners: current and the new one?). You just update the owner in the `pokemon_unique` table and create a row to the `trade` (one row for each pokemon).

Maybe I missed something. Hopefully not.